# discord.py I'm trying to make an afk command from my server, and every time i run my bot it gives an error

Tags: python, cmd, command, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm trying to make an afk command for my server, and whenever i run it in cmd, it gives this error:

```
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an 
    exception: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 
    'change_nickname'
```

Im not sure why. Could anyone who knows a decent amount about discord.py help me with it?
Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix="!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f"Hi {member.name}, welcome to the chiaravalle discord server, please read the rules")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def yeet(ctx):
    await ctx.send("{0.author.mention} hit a yeet!".format(ctx.message))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def afk(ctx, mins):
    await ctx.send("{0.author.mention} has gone afk for {1} minutes.".format(ctx, mins))
    await client.change_nickname(ctx.author.mention, "{0.author.mention} [AFK]".format(ctx))
    counter = 0
    while counter != mins:
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
    if counter == mins:
        await ctx.send("{0.author.mention} is no longer AFK".format(ctx))


bot.run("my token")
client.run("my token")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into at the moment is that you have to change someone's nickname in a different way. You can edit someone's information by using [Member.edit()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit).

Below is a working example of the code you sent and it also resets the nickname back to without the [AFK].

```
@bot.command()
async def afk(ctx, mins):
    current_nick = ctx.author.nick
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has gone afk for {mins} minutes.")
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=f"{ctx.author.name} [AFK]")

    counter = 0
    while counter <= int(mins):
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if counter == int(mins):
            await ctx.author.edit(nick=current_nick)
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is no longer AFK")
            break
```

Comment: its saying no permissions, any help?

Comment: Are you trying to do it to yourself? I'm pretty sure it doesn't work because you're the serverowner. It works on other people with administrator permissions though.

Comment: why would it not work for the owner, also its not working for anyone else so far

Comment: The serverowner is like an untouchable admin, even without any roles on your server the serverowner will have admin permissions. And about others, your bots permissions might not be set up correctly, this is working on my own server. Try dragging the bots role all the way to the top in the role list.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def afk(ctx, reason=None):
    current_nick = ctx.author.nick
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is afk: {reason} ")
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=f"[AFK] {ctx.author.name}")

    counter = 0
    while counter <= int(mins):
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if counter == int(mins):
            await ctx.author.edit(nick=current_nick)
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is no longer AFK")
            break
```

When I tested your command, it said:

```
@2vw has gone afk for AFK minutes
```

IF the reason was just:
!afk afk